# C# System.Xml doesn't serialize tag if the name is "value"

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, tags

C# System.Xml doesn't serialize tag if the name is "value". Is it feature or bug?

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
public System.Nullable<decimal> value {
    get {
        return this.valueField1;
    }
    set {
        this.valueField1 = value;
    }
}
```

Setting the request:

```
filterGroup.numberFilters[0] = new numberFilter() {
            field = "ID",
            operation = numberOperation.EQUAL,
            value = 99
        };
```

The serialized request:

```
<numberFilters>
  <field>ID</field>
  <operation>EQUAL</operation>
</numberFilters>
```

If I change this tag name to something other, the result is correct

```
<numberFilters>
  <field>ID</field>
  <operation>EQUAL</operation>
  <valueKA>99</valueKA>
</numberFilters>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? I cannot [reproduce the behavior](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lD5Hfa)

Answer (score 0):

Your property definition looks wonky. "value" is generally a reserved keyword in the setter. Suggest you rename public property to Value, and keep backing field valueField1.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
public System.Nullable<decimal> value { <-- this 
    get {
        return this.valueField1;
    }
    set {
        this.valueField1 = value; <-- and this cant be the same.
    }
}
```

Comment: The setter is working. Later I can get the setted value. I looked it up and only reserved word iis n the xml is the "xml"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
There is an another getter/setter in the generated class: valueSpecified.

This needs to be set to 'true'

```
filterGroup.numberFilters[0] = new numberFilter() {
        field = "ID",
        operation = numberOperation.EQUAL,
        value = 99,
        valueSpecified = true
    };
```